# Ask in a web form for the path of a file accessed from a user's computer

Tags: asp.net, filepath

In a web form (aspx) I want to ask the user for the path of a file that needs to be used by one of our team.

At first it was a simple textbox but a lot of people send us wrong path (copy/paste seemed too hard for them).

So I tried to use an input file to be sure the path exists but noticed that the file is then send with the form. As the files can weight hundreds of Mb that was not acceptable.

Then I found a way with Jquery to use the input file to get the path of the file without sending it : it works fine on IE but Chrome translate the path in "fakepath". I understand that it is for security reasons.

So I am again looking for a solution, working on all browser, to get from the user the path of a file (with a specific extension) without him being able to write a wrong path.

I hope someone will have the brillant idea I am unable to find :-).

Answer (score 0):

How about receiving only a few kilobytes of the file data from stream instead of the whole file to ensure the path points to a valid file.

Comment: Hello, nice idea I didn't think that it was possible. But even though what I need here is the real path of the file and Chrome would still send me a "fakepath" answer right ?

Comment: @Yannick, even if chrome gives you a fakepath, if you can read from the stream you can be sure that the path entered by the user points to a valid file on his system.